# Insert overwrite external table partitioned data in Hive via Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark with hive in my project . In the spark job , I am doing insert overwrite external table having partitioned columns. Spark job runs fine without any errors , I can see in web-UI, all tasks for the job are completed .

Now comes the painful part , I can see in logs , spark code processing is complete and now hive is trying to move the hdfs files from staging/temp area to actual table directory of hive table . This is taking forever.  Any inputs to fix this will be highly appreciated ? Please let me know if you want more details

Note : However When I run the same insert overwrite logic directly from hive script , it completes with in few minutes. (Execution engine is TEZ).

Comment: what spark API are you using to save it to Hive? is it `df.saveAsTable` ?  If so bare in mind that spark is a lazy evaluation so it doesn't eval anything until it encounter wide dependencies like shuffle or spark actions.

Comment: Thanks nir . Yes I totally understand that spark is lazily evaluated . I am ruunning sql statement (insert overwrite ) from spark APIs to save the data in hive.

Comment: How many partitions are being generated? Hive partitions are not meant to be too numerous.
What format are you using? Maybe calculating parquet index files is taking a long time.
That "move" part doesn't sound right. The final stage of the job is storing in the final files, there shouldn't be any staging files other than spilling. Are you using bucketing?

Comment: I'm facing similar issues where hive is taking forever to move from staging to actual directory. I'm trying to use INSERT OVERWRITE to update 2GB of data into a ~1TB table with 2k to 3k partitions. Does that mean INSERT OVERWRITE is not the solution? What other efficient alternatives are available?